# EEA Family status retain

Tags: united-kingdom, family, residence-cards

I am EEA citizen, Portugal, and have been living in the UK since 2018 summer. My two children joined me here recently on a family visa and received their UK residency cards. I am planning to leave the UK and travel for 3 months. Both kids are over 18. Do it leave them in any kind of legal problem if they continue staying in the UK.

Second, with Brexit issues, it says to apply for Settled and pre-settled status  I need to be living in the UK by 29th of March. Does it mean I can travel freely after 29th of march? I was planning to leave in April 2019.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't your children also Portuguese citizens?  If so, they do not need any visa or residence permit.  If not, did they really join you on a family visa, or was it an EEA family permit (which is entirely different from a legal point of view)?

Comment: Thanks, Sorry let me clarify. They are not a citizen of the EU. They are from outside of the EU. They are here on  EEA family permit and received their residency card of a family member of EU citizen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They are here on EEA family permit and received their residency card of a family member of EU citizen.

Actually, they don't need either of those documents to remain in the UK.  All they need is for you to be residing in the UK.  A temporary absence will not deprive them of their right to remain in the UK, even if the absence is as long as three months.

> Second, with Brexit issues, it says to apply for Settled and pre-settled status I need to be living in the UK by 29th of March. Does it mean I can travel freely after 29th of march? I was planning to leave in April 2019.

The likelihood that the cutoff date will be 29 March seems virtually nil at this point.  But whatever the cutoff date may be, you ought to be able to travel while your application is pending.